# VLCJ audio visualizer output

Tags: java, audio, vlcj

I am using VLCJ to create a program playing videos. I want to show audio visualization in my playing panel in behind My video canvas. I added this argument to the `EmbeddedMediaPlayer` as `--audio-visual=visual`. After running program the audio visualization is shown on main playing context(canvas) and video player is shown in a new frame. Is there any way to have control on both audio visualization and Video output in two canvases then I can add them on my GUI form behind each other.